# Doctrine 2 ORM DateTime field in identifier

Tags: doctrine-orm

In our DB tables, we columns `refID` and `date` are a composite primary key, with one field of the identifier being mapped as a `datetime`:

```php
class corpWalletJournal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="refID", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $refID;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)     
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $date;

    public function setRefID($refID)
    {
        $this->refID = $refID;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTime $date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;
    }
}
```

If we describe them in entity as @ORM\Id this code will return exception "cannot convert datetime to string"...

```php
$filter = array(
    'date' => $this->stringToDate($loopData['date']), 
    'refID' => $loopData['refID']
));

$oCorpWJ = $this->em->getRepository('EveDataBundle:corpWalletJournal')->findOneBy($filter);
// ...
$oCorpWJ->setDate($this->stringToDate($loopData['date']));
// ...
```

If we describe `corpWalletJournal#date` as a simple column, code works fine. Why?

How can we deal with it? We need to have both `date` and `refID` in the primary key.

**ADDED:**

So i created new class

```
use \DateTime;

class DateTimeEx extends DateTime
{

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
}

}
```

And new type for it

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;
use Eve\DataBundle\Entity\Type\DateTimeEx;

class DateTimeEx extends Type
{
    const DateTimeEx = 'datetime_ex';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'my_datetime_ex';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return new DateTimeEx($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::DateTimeEx;
    }

    public function canRequireSQLConversion()
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

How can i use them in entity?

My (edited) Type Class

```
    use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class DateTimeEx extends Type
{
    const DateTimeEx = 'datetime_ex';

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'my_datetime_ex';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::DateTimeEx;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Doctrine 2 ORM needs to convert identifier fields to strings in the [`UnitOfWork`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L1328). This is required to have the `EntityManager` being able to track changes to your objects.

Since objects of type `DateTime` don't natively implement method [`__toString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring), converting them to strings is not as simple as casting them to strings.

Therefore, the default `date`, `datetime` and `time` types [are not supported as part of the identifier](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/2433).

To deal with it, you should define your own [custom field type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types) `mydatetime` mapped to your own `MyDateTime` class which implements `__toString`. That way, the ORM can handle identifiers also if they contain objects.

Here's an example of how that class may look like:

```php
class MyDateTime extends \DateTime 
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->format('U');
    }
}
```

And here's an example of how the custom DBAL type would look like:

```php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class MyDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $dateTime = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);
        
        if ( ! $dateTime) {
            return $dateTime;
        }

        $val = new MyDateTime('@' . $dateTime->format('U'));
        $val->setTimezone($dateTime->getTimezone());
        return $val;
    }

    public function requiresSQLCommentHint(AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mydatetime';
    }
}
```

Then you register it with your ORM configuration during bootstrap (depends on the framework you are using). In symfony, it is documented on the [symfony doctrine documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types).

After that, you can use it in your entities:

```php
class corpWalletJournal
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="mydatetime", nullable=false)     
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $date;
```

Comment: can you explain, where and how i need to change class DateTime? and how use it on my example

Comment: You simply have to extend the `DateTime` class with your own `class MyDateTime extends \DateTime { public function __toString() { return $this->format('U'); } }`. I updated the answer. The rest is in the linked docs (link to custom field types: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#custom-mapping-types )

Comment: i added code\classes to top post, can you explain how can i use them?

Comment: @user1954544 I added the full example

Comment: i got it, and seems it works! but have still question. can we NOT create class DateTimeEx? and make everything we need in type class?

Comment: I just called it `MyDateTime` in my example. Anyway, it's necessary to define a custom type, since doctrine will use that type for creating new instances when reading data from DB during hydration. Without the custom type, it will use the simple `DateTime` and simply fail (same error you had previously).

Comment: and if i want it return and insert as simple string, but in db was as "datetime" can i simple use (in Type class) $value? (i'll show class in top post)

Comment: If it is a `DateTime`, it is not a string. Doctrine expects to find the mapped types in the properties, and will crash if your data is invalid.

Comment: one last question, why we use convertToPHPValue method to solve the problem? how does this "mechanism" works? what converts in what and what is the order of using this methods? i thought we have to use convertToDataBaseValue ....

Comment: `convertToDataBaseValue` turns your field into something that the SQL layer understands. `convertToPHPValue` turns the SQL value into something your application (And the ORM) understands. Check the DBAL docs for more info: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html

Comment: docs is poor enough, that's why i'm asking, anyway thanks for help, problem solved ;)

Comment: @user1954544 if documentation is poor, fork it and help ;)

Comment: I'm having the same error after following that steps, Warning: Illegal offset type, how did you solve the issue?

Comment: I've noticed some side-effects of this: 1) The **doctrine:schema:update** tool continually tries to update the custom date fields because Doctrine's `Comparator` sees `DateTime` in the database and `MyDateTime` in the local code. 2) You must convert any values used to query this field to the same type as the custom type, so for example `$queryBuilder->setParameter('date', new MyDateTime('@'.$dateTime->format('U')))`.

Comment: Can't believe how much time I've spent on this. Just want to return datetime value as string!

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be much more efficient to convert to an int timestamp instead of a string?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful with

```
return new DateTimeEx('@' . $dateTime->format('U'));
```

The timezone won't be good. You should do :

```
$val = new DateTimeEx('@' . $dateTime->format('U'));
$val->setTimezone($dateTime->getTimezone());

return $val;
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Ocramius [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15085566/4847251):

```php
namespace App\Interface;

interface StringableDateTimeInterface extends \DateTimeInterface, \Stringable
{
}
```

```php
namespace App\Type;

use App\Interface\StringableDateTimeInterface;

class DateTime extends \DateTime implements StringableDateTimeInterface
{
    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->format('U');
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\DBAL;

use App\Type\DateTime;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType as DoctrineDateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class DateTimeType extends DoctrineDateTimeType
{
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): mixed
    {
        $dateTime = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);

        if (!$dateTime) {
            return $dateTime;
        }

        $val = new DateTime('@' . $dateTime->format('U'));
        $val->setTimezone($dateTime->getTimezone());

        return $val;
    }
}
```

```php
namespace App\DBAL;

use App\Type\DateTime;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType as DoctrineDateType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class DateType extends DoctrineDateType
{
    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform): mixed
    {
        $dateTime = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);

        if (!$dateTime) {
            return $dateTime;
        }

        $val = new DateTime('@' . $dateTime->format('U'));
        $val->setTimezone($dateTime->getTimezone());

        return $val;
    }
}
```

then add in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml`

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            datetime: App\DBAL\DateTimeType
            date: App\DBAL\DateType
```

And finally in your Entity use like:

```php
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'date')]
    private ?StringableDateTimeInterface $date;

    public function getDate(): ?StringableDateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(StringableDateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }
```

Don't forget to create new `App\Type\DateTime` and not `DateTime` when setting the values of instance.