# Taking a datetime field into primary key throws fatal error

Tags: mysql, datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to use the combination of two foreign keys plus the datetime field as my combined primary key.

But I get a

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string in
>   C:\development\xampp\htdocs\happyfaces\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php
>   line 1337

when I do so. As soon as I remove the `id: true` from my YML entity declaration everything works fine again.

What is the problem that occurs here? It seems to be rather a Symfony2 or a Doctrine2 bug to me, because the datetime is set fine in the database if I don't declare the datetime column to be part of the primary key.

Can anyone help or advise?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its not possible and not recommended. For primary key focus on primitive data types such as `Integer` or `String`. The most RDMS System prefer `Integer` as primary key for maximum performance.

Take look: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/2.1/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html

Maybe a workaround could work by adding a new Doctrine data type. With a `__toString()` function, but I think Doctrine will force you to use primitive data types only.

```
class Foo
{
    private $bar = 'test';

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

echo new Foo();
```

Your error means in general `DateTime` has no `__toString()` function or is not string compatible. I never tested it to use a custom data type as primary key. So you've to try it yourself.

Take a look: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html

Another try is use `String` as Primary key and set your `id` with

```
$entity->setId(new \DateTime()->format('yyyy/mm/dd'));
```

Here is a similar question: [Symfony/Doctrine: DateTime as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125863/symfony-doctrine-datetime-as-primary-key)