# Multiversion concurrency control with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, mvcc

We would like to implement [Multiversion concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) for our Symfony2 webapp.

This means that on any event, no `UPDATE` is performed on the database, but only `INSERT`s. As I haven't found any native support by Symfony2 for this requirement, I made up my mind how this could be implemented manually.

Besides the regular ID (primary key) of each entity (e.g. a `User`), we add another entity property, e.g. another `userID`. So on each change of the user attributes, we could simply `INSERT` another row for the user, which then has another `ID`, but the same `userID`.

The entity could then always be identified by the specific additional entity ID.

But there are a couple of problems that come up with this solution: The regular entity ID is the primary key and therefore the identifier for all relations to this entity. One could also try to create combined primary keys (e.g. `ID` plus `timestamp`, or `ID` plus `entityID`)<strike>, but Symfony2/Doctrine2 is not constructed to support combined primary keys</strike>.

So how would you approach to implement a MVCC in Symfony2/Doctrine2? Do you see a way to handle this? Or would you recommend to use a separate history table that keeps track of all changes?

Comment: Take a look at the [Loggable](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/loggable.md) extension.

Comment: _but Symfony2/Doctrine2 is not constructed to support combined primary keys_ [Are you sure?](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

Comment: @n.1 Oh you're right. I was confusing it with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874646/1828051). I updated my question. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: @Pazi, looks promising. Thanks for the hint.