# Symfony 2 form with date as key but not on form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

So I have this simple form in symfony where I only have 3 fields. All ids working to here one entity that is not on form but it's in the DB is column df_date and it's type DATE in DB.

**Here is that entity:**

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date")
 * @ORM\Id
 */

 protected $df_date;

 /**
 * Set df_date
 *
 * @param \DateTime $dfDate
 * @return WeatherSpecials
 */

public function setDfDate($dfDate)
{
    $this->df_date = $dfDate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get df_date
 *
 * @return \DateTime 
 */

public function getDfDate()
{
    return $this->df_date;
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public function ajax_weather_specialsAction(Request $request, $main_id)
{

    $params = array();

    if (!$main_id) {
        /*
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:WeatherSpecials');
        $weather_specials = $repository->find($main_id);
        */
    } else {
        $weather_specials = new WeatherSpecials;
    }

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($weather_specials)
        ->add('df_weather', 'choice', array(
            'choices'  => array(
                null, 'SU', 'PC', 'CL', 'RN'
            ),
            'label' => false, 'required' => true,
        ))
        ->add('df_temptur', 'number', array('label' => false, 'required' => true))
        ->add('df_specday', 'text', array('label' => false, 'required' => false))
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($weather_specials);

            // How to set df_date here???

            $em->flush();
        }
    }

    $data['status'] = 'success';
    $data['html'] = $this->render('sales_tabs/weather_specials.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()))->getContent();

    return new JsonResponse($data);
}
```

And the question is, how to set the df_date before I persist that form to the DB?

Comment: what value do you want to persist? the current time?

Comment: Any date, yyyy-mm-dd, no time needed.

Comment: the filed is defined as primary key, so if you want to prevent duplicated keys, i suggest you to store a timestamp, better a simple auto-increment? check the doc here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

Comment: date is ok as the logic makes sure it runs once a day. so it will not duplicate.

Comment: sorry but i think you have already tried with `$weather_specials->setDfDate(new \DateTime());`without success. perhaps is the correct php type defined in the doctrine2 docs here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#date

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `WeatherSpecials` is the entity that you want to set `df_date` on either set it before you persist;

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $weather_specials->setDfDate(new \DateTime());
    $em->persist($weather_specials);
    $em->flush();
}
```

or use the [doctrine HasLifecycleCallbacks](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html);

```
/**
 * WeatherSpecials
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="weather_specials")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\WeatherSpecialsRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class WeatherSpecials
{
    // other stuff

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist
     */
    public function prePersist(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $this->df_date = new DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate(\Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $this->df_date = new DateTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the error I get. Stack Trace

    in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php at line 1359  -
            public function addToIdentityMap($entity)
            {
                $classMetadata = $this->em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
                $idHash        = implode(' ', $this->entityIdentifiers[spl_object_hash($entity)]);
                if ($idHash === '') {
                    throw ORMInvalidArgumentException::entityWithoutIdentity($classMetadata->name, $entity);

Answer (score 0):

You can set the date manually before persisting the entity.

Consider the following piece of code

```
if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $weather_specials->setDfDate(new \DateTime());

        $em->persist($weather_specials);
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

This will set the date to the current date and time. You can change the datetime values according to your needs.

You can even use Doctrine's `preUpdate` or `prePersist` callbacks.

**UPDATE** Your entity definition is incorrect. You should define `$df_date` as a `\Datetime` parameter. Change this in your code

```
/**
* @var \datetime
* @ORM\Column(type="date")
* @ORM\Id
*/

protected $df_date;

//the rest of your stuff
```

Comment: when I add $weather_specials->setDfDate(new \DateTime());. I get this error Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Comment: Are you sure you added `new \DateTime()` with the \?

Comment: See my edit. You are missing out `* @var \datetime` in the definition of your entity for the variable `$df_date`

Comment: I added the * @var \datetime and I still get that error, I'm on symfony 2.8 can that be the reason?

Comment: Try removing the return statement in your `setDfDate` and remove `* @return WeatherSpecials` from above the method. Don't return anything in short.

Comment: I did that and now I get this error: Entity of type AppBundle\Entity\WeatherSpecials is missing an assigned ID for field 'df_date'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

Comment: Add `$weather_specials = new WeatherSpecials();` i.e. add brackets at the end of `WeatherSpecials` like `()`

Comment: Sorry I can't think of anything else

Comment: Thanks Dipen for your help. I'll start over. maybe a missed something here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and Doctrine can kiss my ... with it's recommendations. It took me 3 days to figure this one out, it wold take me 5 minutes to figure that in PHP alone.  [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874023/taking-a-datetime-field-into-primary-key-throws-fatal-error)