# Symfony 3: Doctrine dateTime problems row

Tags: php, datetime, orm, doctrine, symfony

I have a ORM\Entity with a column date type. When I use EntityManager to select object to Update I have these error: "Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string"

Column:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date")
 */
private $date;
```

And the query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT t FROM AppBundle:Table t WHERE t.id = :t_id')->setParameter('t_id', $tId);
$result = $query->getResult(); // <- ¡ERROR IS HERE!
```

ERROR:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A date/datetime can't be used as a unique ID with Doctrine, because it requires a __toString() method. You can create this class :

```
class DoctrineDateTime extends DateTime
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->format('U');
    }
}
```

Instead of setting your "$date" field with a DateTime object, use this class.
Do the same thing for your requests on the ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reason why it is not advised at all to use a DateTime as a unique id.

Another way to do it is use set your primary key of the String type, and do:

`$entity->setId(new \DateTime()->format('yyyy/mm/dd'));`

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18874646/3062315 for reference!