# ORM cannot convert datetime to a string because datetime used as Primary key

Tags: symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I have a problem because I am using an existing database and in lot of table they use primary key with several foreign key and some includes Datetime.

And so when you do this:

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DT_DEBUT", type="date")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $dtDebut;
```

Then running server gives you an erreur such as:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Then I discovered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080573/doctrine-2-orm-datetime-field-in-identifier/46829619#46829619) and tried to use the solution but I am still having problems.

Here is MyDateTime.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateTimeType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * Custom datatype to convert dateTime into a string
 */
class MyDateTimeType extends DateTimeType
{
    const MYDATETIME = 'mydatetime'; 

    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return 'MyDateTime';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $dateTime = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);

        if ( ! $dateTime) {
            return $dateTime;
        }

        return new MyDateTime('@' . $dateTime->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MYDATETIME;
    }
}
```

And I made an other file MyDateTime.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Types;

class MyDateTime extends \Datetime 
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    }
}
```

And last, of course, I updated my config.xml with:

```
types:
            mydatetime: AppBundle\Types\MyDateTimeType
```

But I am having this NEW issue:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (@1999-03-18 12:00:00) at position 8 (-): Double timezone specification

Can anyone help me please? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony/Doctrine: DateTime as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125863/symfony-doctrine-datetime-as-primary-key)

Comment: Yes i saw this post and i did what Amik said like in the other post i put the link of. But then i have an error of double timezone and that is why i created this post. Check out at the end of mine, thank you :)