# Doctrine2 Unique Validation with multiple fields

Tags: php, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have an entity `Booking` which has a many-to-one relationship to a `User`.
Each `Booking` entity has a `date` field which should be unique to the user.

For example entries could look like this:

```
+----------+---------+
|   date   | user_id |
+----------+---------+
| 12-04-88 |       1 |
| 13-04-88 |       1 |
| 12-04-88 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

But not like this:

```
+----------+---------+
|   date   | user_id |
+----------+---------+
| 12-04-88 |       1 |
| 12-04-88 |       1 |
+----------+---------+
```

The code to add a `Booking` entity, is as follows, using the ZF2 REST controller:

### Input Filter

```
class BookingFilter extends InputFilter
{

    //TODO: Get from module config
    protected $config = array(
        'date-format'   => 'd-m-Y',
        'start-min'     => '07:00',
        'start-max'     => '10:00',
        'end-min'       => '16:00',
        'end-max'       => '19:00',
        'step'          => '900', //15 x 60 - 15 Min's
    );

    public function init()
    {

        $this->add(
            array(
                'name'      => 'date',
                'required'  => true,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'Date',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'format' => 'd-m-Y',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );

        $this->add(
            array(
                'name'      => 'startTime',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'Date',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'format' => 'H:i',
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'GreaterThan',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'min'       => $this->config['start-min'],
                            'inclusive' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'LessThan',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'max'       => $this->config['start-max'],
                            'inclusive' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'DateStep',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'format'    => 'H:i',
                            'baseValue' => $this->config['start-min'],
                            'step'      => new \DateInterval("PT{$this->config['step']}S"),
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
            )
        );

        $this->add(
            array(
                'name'      => 'endTime',
                'required'  => true,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'Date',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'format' => 'H:i',
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'GreaterThan',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'min'       => $this->config['end-min'],
                            'inclusive' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'LessThan',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'max'       => $this->config['end-max'],
                            'inclusive' => true,
                        ),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'      => 'DateStep',
                        'options'   => array(
                            'format'    => 'H:i',
                            'baseValue' => $this->config['end-min'],
                            'step'      => new \DateInterval("PT{$this->config['step']}S"),
                        ),
                    ),

                ),
            )
        );

        //notes
        $this->add(
            array(
                'name'      => 'notes',
                'required'  => false,
                'filters'   => array(
                    array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'StringLength',
                        'options' => array(
                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                            'min'      => 1,
                            'max'      => 512,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

### Controller Action

```
public function create($data)
{

    $user    = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity();
    $booking = $this->getTimeBookingService()->validateBooking($data, $user);
        
    $booking->setUser($user);
    //some other stuff
    //persist
}
```

### Service

```
public function validateBooking(array $data, UserInterface $user, Booking $booking = null)
{
    $filter = $this->getInputFilter();
    $filter->setData($data);

    if (!$filter->isValid()) {
        $this->messages = $filter->getMessages();
        return false;
    }

    if (!$booking) {
        $booking = new Booking;
    }
    $this->getDoctrineHydrator()->hydrate($filter->getValues(), $booking);

    //if this is a new booking - not an update
    if (!$booking->getId()) {
        $row = $this->bookingRepository->findOneBy(array('date' => $booking->getDate(), 'user' => $user));
        if (is_object($row)) {
            //user already has booking for this date
            $this->messages['date'] = array('This user already has a booking for this date');
            return false;
        }
    }

    return $booking;
}
```

## Question

How can I do this with either a default Doctrine Validator or a custom Doctrine/ZF2 validator?

I don't like my approach it seems like I'm replicating work of the Validator component, however, I couldn't get it to work with the Doctrine Unique Validator last time I tried because there is more than 1 one field which need to be unique.

I was thinking to extend the Doctrine Unique validator with a dependency on the `User` which will be injected an construction and then extending the `validate` method to search the repository using both `date` and `user` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking to extend the Doctrine Unique validator with a
>   dependency on the User which will be injected an construction and then
>   extending the validate method to search the repository using both date
>   and user fields?

Adding some changes to the model, you can set `date` and `user_id` primary key together:

```
/** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
private $id;
/** @Id @Column(type="date") */
private $date;
```

I do not know how your framework controller persist the object, but you could do something like this:

```
try
{
   $booking = new Booking(1, '12-19-2000');
   em->persist($booking);
   em->flush();
}
catch( \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e )
{ 
    /* the error 23000 should print the unique constrains mysql error */
    if( $e->getPrevious()->getCode() === '23000' ) 
    { 
        echo "entity already exists";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check this out tomorrow, my framework is ZF2 and I'm hoping to use the `\DoctrineModule\Validator\UniqueObject` component.

Comment: Just tried this and came across the issue outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080573/doctrine-2-orm-datetime-field-in-identifier/15085566#15085566). Looks like Doctrine2 doesn't support DateTime objects as id's. I'll try the solution and accept if it works :)