# From Array to Doctrine/ArrayCollection: entity id (date) issue

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this scenario

### Entity

```
class Foo
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="date")
   */
  protected $date;

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity"Bar", inversedBy="foo")
   */
  protected $bar;

  [...]
}
```

### Repository

```
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function dummyNameFunction()
  {
    $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('foo')
               ->//some dummy "components" added to builder
               ->getQuery()
    ;

    //I need an ArrayCollection as I want to take advantage of
    //Doctrine's ArrayCollection filter() function
    return new ArrayCollection($q->getResult()); 
  }
}
```

### The issue

As long as I try to fecth data from db, I obtain this error

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime
>   could not be converted to string in
>   /path/to/project/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   line 2504

To me this is "pretty clear": into conversion from `Array` of Objects into `ArrayCollection`, Doctrine would like to index brand new `ArrayCollection` with id(s) of entity but, as key is a datetime, no `__toString()` method (or equivalent) is provided by PHP itself.

Possible solutions that came in my mind:

- Add an integer field as id. Remove id from `$date` and `$bar` and put a constraint to make them unique. Cons: I have a filed that will be perfectly useless.
- <s>[Register](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) a doctrine custom mapping type that will be, basically, a `Date` with __toString magic method. Cons: I don't now if this works as I haven't tried yet.</s>.Second solution seems to work but not with __toString() magic method. It's a little "hack" and it's a little bit dirty. You can find the solution below (*)

### Questions

1. Someone knows better or "faster" method compared to my two possible solutions?
2. (Side question) Is this a "real" issue? It's possible that Doctrine2 devel haven't thought about dates as keys?

### Dirty solution (*)

First of all you need to define a Doctrine2 costum type. How can you do that?
I've created a folder inside my bundle (to keep Doctrine2 original bundle structure safe) at `Doctrine\DBAL\Types`. Then, inside, I've created this class

```
<?php

namespace Company\BundleName\Doctrine\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\DateType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class CustomDate extends DateType
{
    private $date_value;

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'custom_date';
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $date = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);
        $this->date_value = $date;

        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return ($value !== null)
            ? $value : null;
    }
}
```

Then I have added a boot() method to bundle bootstrap file (the file you need to register bundle inside AppKernel.php)

```
public function boot()
{
    $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    Type::addType('custom_date', 'Company\BundleName\Doctrine\DBAL\Types\CustomDate');
    $em->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping('custom_date','custom_date');
}
```

After that I've mod. mapping of Foo's `$date` variable

```
  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="custom_date")
   */
  protected $date;
```

#### Pay attention: if you use any type hint, remember to change getters and setters properly

Comment: In my experience, it is always a good idea to use `auto_increment` ids as primary keys for tables... Any other field will give you some headaches.

Comment: @OscarPérez: If they give you the chance to use other type for id(s) I trust that those types will work fine aswell integers one so I'm here waiting for someone that knows how to fix that without adding an extra field. C'mon, there should be a method! :) PS.: Updated my question, second method didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only solution is to create a brand new doctrine type (what I called "dirty solution" here) because UnitOfWork need string or integer to work properly.

Source: [Doctrine 2 ORM DateTime field in identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080573/doctrine-2-orm-datetime-field-in-identifier)