# Symfony2 Can't create fixtures with dates

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I try to use fixtures in unit test. DB - pdo_sqlite, Doctrine2 
I have class:
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * Statspg
 * @ORM\Table(name="statsPG")
 */
class Statspg
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="`date`", type="datetime")
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="groupid", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $groupid;
```

and fixture yaml file:

```
Acme\StatisticsBundle\Entity\Statspg:
  Stat0:
     date: <(new \DateTime('2014-02-02'))>
     groupid: testGroupId0
```

When I run test that setup textures I get a error:

> Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string
>
> /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1413
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1226
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:915
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1683
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php:1639
>   /vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php:579
>   /vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/ORM/Doctrine.php:37
>   /vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Fixtures.php:130
>   /vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Fixtures.php:104
>   /vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Fixtures.php:57
>   /vendor/liip/functional-test-bundle/Test/WebTestCase.php:458
>   /src/Acme/AcmeBundle/Tests/Controller/Rest/GroupControllerTest.php:14

What I do wrong?

**UPDATE**

Find [Doctrine 2 ORM DateTime field in identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080573/doctrine-2-orm-datetime-field-in-identifier)

and now I understand that problem is with Primary Key that \DateTime

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a datetime column as the primary key and not a simple id field?  It seems like it would be better practice to use a normal integer id for your primary, and then a unique datetime column if you really wanted that to be unique and still be indexed.

Comment: I don't want to add field that I not gonna use it, just for satisfy doctrina. I have composite PK by group id and date, it's all what I need. But because I work with doctrine and I don't want to add my data type, I don't see other way, just my PK make unique key and add useless id field for PK.

Comment: Did you try the solution from your link?  That should work.  I understand not wanting to add another field, but I've always found it easiest to just give every table it's own integer PK even if there is a composite key that would do the same - for me it's always easier referencing a single id for querying, deleting, etc., and just making the other key unique.